# how to use address defined in linkerscript in C source file?

Tags: c, gcc, linker-scripts

In a C application, I want to place a big buffer at an address after the variables, stack and dma address ranges. Of course I can define a section in the wanted location in the linker script and declare a big array in C and give a section attribute to the array. But I want to do it without actually declaring the big array because it makes the executable too big. I want to use the array address to do the same.
I'm using gcc and try to use an address I define in the linker script inside the C source file.
Here is how I tried it.
in the linker script file (which is ldabtsm.lds.S in my case),

```
...
    . = ALIGN(16777216);
    .vimbuffs : {
        *(.vimbuffs)
    }
    vimbuffs = .;
...
```

I tried using vimbuffs in the C source file.
So I did (if I can print, I can use it anyway..)

```
extern unsigned int vimbuffs; // from linker script
printf("vimbuffs = %x\n", vimbuffs);
```

From the map file, I can see the vimbufs is assigned to 0x3b3f6000 which is just right, I want it to be aligned. But when run the program and print the value, I see

```
vimbuffs = a07f233d
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Please also show the code which ended up in too big an executable, with the map file showing the sizes.

Comment: You are printing the *value* of `vimbuffs`, not its *address*. Try `printf("vimbuffs = %x\n", &vimbuffs);`

Comment: @jiahd right, I soon found that I should use &vimbuffs. Thanks.